# Adding an item dynamically in kendo combobox

Tags: jquery, html, css, combobox, kendo-ui

If anyone of you have used kendo ui than can you please let me know how to add a new item dynamically in kendo combobox.

I have tried searching on google and everywhere and my conclusion is that there is no such feature in kendo.

For reference - [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/ebutaw/2/edit#source)

kendo link - [here](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/combobox/index.html)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As you probably know, there are two way to create a combobox (select and input). I was not able to add a new item dynamically using select (like your example). However, using the input and databinding, it is simple.

```
$("#comboBox").data("kendoComboBox").dataSource.add({ text: "Five", value: "5" });
```

[JSBIN example 1](http://jsbin.com/ebutaw/3/edit#source).
[JSBIN example 2](http://jsbin.com/ebutaw/4/edit).

Comment: Great !! Thanks. I will use your solution. I don't mind changing `<select>` to `<input>`.

Comment: This code doesn't work correctly in 2018. I should use upper case for "text" and "value": `$("#comboBox").data("kendoComboBox").dataSource.add({ Text: "Five", Value: "5" });`