# how to insert value into the kendo combo box

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

If I have a kendo combobox that contains more than 1 value I would like to insert "-ALL- as the DataTextField and "9999" as the DataValueField. Currently, if I have only a single record I use the DataBound event to test for that and if it = 1 then I load a grid based on this value, but if the length > 1 then I would like to add the -All-. I don't understand the insert as described by telerik.

```
        @(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
      .Name("FAList")
      .Placeholder("Select Fiscal Agency...")
      .DataTextField("Text")
      .DataValueField("Value")
      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:50%;" })
      .Filter("startswith")
      .AutoBind(true)
      .MinLength(3)
      .DataSource(source =>
      {
          source.Read(read =>
          {
              read.Action("GetUserAgencyList", "Entities");
          })
          .ServerFiltering(true);
      })
          .Events(e => e
            .Change("onFAChange")
            .DataBound("onFADataBound")
            )
)
```

and then the function for binding the data

```
        function onFADataBound(e) {
    // the agency list dropdown
    var combobox = $("#FAList").data("kendoComboBox");
    // if there is only a single record then set that in the combobox and load the grid based on that
    if (e.sender.dataSource.view().length == 1) {
        e.sender.select(0);
        var filter = this.value();
        $.get('/City/CityGrid_Read', { id: filter }, function (data) {
            var grid = $("#FollowUpGrid").data("kendoGrid");
            grid.dataSource.read();
        })
    }
    if (e.sender.dataSource.view().length > 1) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Answered at: [Adding an item dynamically in kendo combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11261113/adding-an-item-dynamically-in-kendo-combobox)

Combining that with your code:

```
if (e.sender.dataSource.view().length > 1) {   

$("#FAList").data("kendoComboBox").dataSource.add({ Text: "-All-",
Value: "0" }); 

}
```

Something like that! I hope you get this implemented :)

An alternative could be to change the Placeholder text in this event method where length > 1

as per example on: http://www.telerik.com/forums/placeholder-text

```
$("#FAList").data("kendoComboBox").input.attr("placeholder", "-All-");
```

Comment: I tried the above suggestion and got a list of undefined, so I tried the insert and again got a list of undefined.

Comment: Perhaps try capitalizing Text and Value in the new line of code? My other thought is after running the line to add to datasource, try calling the data source bind method on the combobox so it re-binds with the newly added data source object? Hope you get it working!